# How to fix save matrix into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to add the matrix into linked list such as:
[image: exemple]
But my code can't save the matrix, and when print matix, It all 0

My code:

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse *m, int t[N][M], size_t Nlign, size_t Ncol) {
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nlign;
    m->liste = malloc(Nlign * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Nlign; i++) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
        element* dernier = m->liste[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element* e = malloc(sizeof(element)); 
                e->col = j;
                e->val = t[i][j];
                e->suiv = NULL;
                if (dernier != NULL) 
                    dernier->suiv  = e; 
                else // Sinon
                    dernier = e; 
                dernier = dernier->suiv; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main code:

```
int mat[4][5] = {{0, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    matrice_creuse m1;
    construcMat(&m1, mat, 4, 5);
```

Comment: You still have to assign `dernier` to `m->liste[i]`

Comment: For a truely sparse matrix, you should also have sparse rows.

Comment: `int t[N][M]`: Where are N and M declared?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie N, M is defined, matrix t[N][M] is normal, and you said to sign `dernier` to `m->liste[i]`, I did in the loop of i

Answer (score 1):

You still have to put the list in `m->liste[i]`. You can do that with a doublepointer; see below:

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse *m, int t[N][M], size_t Nlign, size_t Ncol) {
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nlign;
    m->liste = malloc(Nlign * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Nlign; i++) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
        element **dernier = &m->liste[i];       // use a double indirection
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element* e = malloc(sizeof(element)); 
                e->col = j;
                e->val = t[i][j];
                e->suiv = NULL;

                *dernier= e;        // assign it..
                dernier= &e->suiv;  //..and advance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I want to use a only one pointer in `dernier`? I think `m->liste[i]` is head and, dernier is assigned into `m->liste[i]->suiv`

Answer (score 1):

`dernier` is one more pointer, initially it points to same location where `m->liste[i]` is pointing.

With below line, you are making `dernier` to point to some other location and it won't make `m->liste[i]` to point to new location.

```
dernier = e;
```

Have `dernier` as pointer to pointer.

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse *m, int t[N][M], size_t Nlign, size_t Ncol) {
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nlign;
    m->liste = malloc(Nlign * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Nlign; i++) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
        element** dernier = &m->liste[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element* e = malloc(sizeof(element)); 
                e->col = j;
                e->val = t[i][j];
                e->suiv = NULL;
                if ((*dernier) != NULL) 
                    (*dernier)->suiv  = e; 
                else // Sinon
                    (*dernier) = e; 
                dernier = &(*dernier)->suiv; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**
Without using pointer to pointer.

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse *m, int t[N][M], size_t Nlign, size_t Ncol) {
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nlign;
    m->liste = malloc(Nlign * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Nlign; i++) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
        element* dernier = m->liste[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element* e = malloc(sizeof(element)); 
                e->col = j;
                e->val = t[i][j];
                e->suiv = NULL;
                if (dernier != NULL) {
                    dernier->suiv  = e;
                    dernier = dernier->suiv;
                 }                  
                else {// Sinon
                    dernier = e; 
                    m->liste[i] = dernier;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I want to use a only one pointer of `dernier`, so what can I do?